# What's the best way to save scaffolding for developer access?

Tags: grails, scaffolding, urlmappings.groovy

I'm working on a project in Grails 2.0.RC1 and I'd like to be able to save the scaffolded controllers and views for my domain objects to have as a "low-level", developer only access to still tinker with things while being able to develop the production version of the views and controllers (with similar names, especially for controllers). I'd like to preserve them as-is, so I can re-generate them as I make updates to the domain layer, so just moving them is most likely not going to work.

I'm hoping there's a way to do some UrlMapping magic that would let me have requests for "/mgr/book" go to the scaffolded Book controller, but "/book" would go to my production controller. I can't find anything in the docs about how to have mappings for specific groups of controllers (without specifying each controller by name versus a $controller notation).

My other thought is to turn my domain layer into a plug-in and then create a separate project that would be just for the scaffolded views. This would be easier to remove before going to production, but also seems like more work, and raises the issue of running two grails apps at the same time on the same box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advance you to go like your last idea. This is also my common approach:

1. Create an embeddable plugin for your domain model and common services. This also includes common plugins, like spring security and stuff. This will also reduce your dependency resolution time for the main-app btw.
2. Create an embeddable plugin for your scaffolded views. Change the template of the scaffolded controllers to require authentication and admin-group.
3. Your main-app uses both plugins.

This keeps your main-app clean and simple and you can still regenerate all your scaffolded views & controllers as you wish. And at least Eclipse STS hot-deployment will still work!

However there is no simple solution for seperating your scaffolded controllers URL-wise yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Security, you should be able to use an [InterceptUrlMap](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#5.2%20Simple%20Map%20in%20Config.groovy) or [RequestMap Instances](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#5.3%20Requestmap%20Instances%20Stored%20in%20the%20Database) to secure the controller URLs.

If your scaffold controllers are only used for scaffolding (and don't have other actions), then you should be able to use basic [Secured annotations](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#5.1%20Defining%20Secured%20Annotations) to secure the entire controller.

Then you can use the scaffolding like normal, protected behind a login.

Other security frameworks may provide similar access control.